# Проверить, является ли выделенный текст жирным? C#

Tags: c#

Есть текст в richTextBox1. Как проверить, является ли выделенная область жирным текстом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выделенной области текста пример кода:

```
  if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont != null)
      {
          if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold == true)
          //что-то делаем
      }
```

Или повесить на событие *Change()